# Bing Maps directions with clustering

Tags: bing-maps

I am able to draw the Map with maneuverPoints.

Below is the screen shot for map

[image]

Below is the code for the routing.

```
var maneuverPoints = this.model.get("maneuverPoints");
        if (maneuverPoints) {
            var routePoints = [];
            _.each(maneuverPoints, function (point) {
                routePoints.push(new MsMaps.Location(point.latitude, point.longitude));
            });
            var routeOptions = {
                strokeColor: new MsMaps.Color(1, 65, 255, 35),
                strokeThickness: 3
            };
            var routeShape = new MsMaps.Polyline(routePoints, routeOptions);
            map.entities.push(routeShape);
        }
```

Now I am trying to implement clustering and I am able to do it as below:

[image]

The pink pushpins are the clusters.

Code for clustering is as below:

Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.Clustering", function () {

```
                var clusterLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(pushpins);
                map.layers.insert(clusterLayer);

                clusterLayer.setPushpins(pushpins);
                map.setView(viewOptions);
                var maneuverPoints = this.model.get("maneuverPoints");
                if (maneuverPoints) {
                    var routePoints = [];
                    _.each(maneuverPoints, function (point) {
                        routePoints.push(new MsMaps.Location(point.latitude, point.longitude));
                    });
                    var routeOptions = {
                        strokeColor: new MsMaps.Color(1, 65, 255, 35),
                        strokeThickness: 3
                    };
                    var routeShape = new MsMaps.Polyline(routePoints, routeOptions);
                    map.entities.push(routeShape);
                }
```

I am not able to do clustering and routing at same time. Is it possible to do both at same time?

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't doing routing by the looks of things, it is simply taking route line points and rendering them as a polyline. I don't see the directions module being used in your code. If you are using that directions module, why don't you simply use the built in rendering? You can customize how it looks. If you continue using a polyline as you are, consider adding it to a layer, it will make it easier to manage later.

That said, the code you provided is simply clustering and drawing a polyline. This works fine when I test this scenario.

Any reason why you are calling setPushpins in the cluster layer? You already passed the pushpins in when creating the layer, no need to pass them in again.